# Yii - URL mamanement optimization

Tags: php, url, yii

I have a table called categories:

- id
- category_name
- parent_id

and the table Products:

- id
- category_id
- product_name

To keep things simple product_name and catogory_name is unique URL aliases

And i want make URL like there

shop/computer_parts/cpu/intel     - is the url of "intel" category which have parents cpu and computer

And Products like

shop/computer_parts/cpu/intel/intel_core_i5_2500k - is product

I see the solution, adding in models methods like

Category model

```
public function geturl() {
    ***in cycle getting aliases of all parents***
    return Yii::app()->createUrl( ...etc
}
```

and Product

```
public function geturl() {
    *** getting aliases of category and parents ***
    return Yii::app()->createUrl( ...etc
}
```

Is it the way to do this more simple?

Answer (score 0):

First, set the urlFormat to path and showScriptName to false in your main config (*protected/config/main.php*):

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'         =>  'path',
    'showScriptName'    =>  false,
    'rules'=>array( 
        ...
```

Next, you need to setup the rules for the URLs in your config , something like:

```
shop/<parent:.+>/<child:.+>/<category:.+>/<product:.+>    => 'product/view',
shop/<parent:.+>/<child:.+>/<category:.+>/                => 'product/index',
```

That points those two URLs to product/view and product/index (obviously this will change to whatever controller/action you have to handle each of these). You will now be able to access all the GET variables from the URL, so for example:

```
$product = $_GET['product'];
```

You will have to write your controller/action to identify what level you are currently on in the URL structure and handle it accordingly.

Comment: No no) i know this, i'm about server's load when i get url's for each product